# Error in native-image GluonFX application when creating a BufferedImage

Tags: gluon-mobile, gluonfx

When my application is built as a native-image with gluonfx:nativeBuild, and I run the application (gluonfx:nativeRun) I get the following error:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no awt in java.library.path
```

This happens in my code where I read a file (or URL) and save as a BufferedImage. I have used ImageIO.read() but also tried with apache-commons-imaging with same results.

```java
try(InputStream is = connection.getInputStream()) {
    image = Imaging.getBufferedImage(is);
}
```

```java
try(InputStream is = ImageUtils.class.getResourceAsStream(path)) {
    image = Imaging.getBufferedImage(is);
}
```

I have tested this on Linux and MacOS with same result.

Works fine when running normally (not natively).

Comment: GraalVM has none or very limited support for AWT (mostly for Linux only), and the GluonFX plugin doesn't link with most of the AWT libraries, therefore you see the error: `no awt in java.library.path`. There are a few alternatives to avoid `BufferedImage` using only JavaFX.